# Python: Unpacking binary file into a 2-d array and giving a length error

Tags: python, arrays, file, python-3.x, unpack

I'm trying to read in data from a file in binary format and store it in a 2-d array. However, I'm getting an error that reads

```
error: unpack requires a bytes object of length 2
```

Essentially what I have is something like

```
import os, struct
from itertools import chain

packets = value1  #The number of packets in the data stream
dataLength = value2 #bytes of data per packet

packHeader = [[0 for x in range(14)] for y in range(packets)]
data = [[0 for x in range(dataLength)] for y in range(packets)]

for i in range(packets):
    packHeader[i][0] = struct.unpack('>H', file.read(2))
    packHeader[i][1] = struct.unpack('>H', file.read(2))
    ....
    packHeader[i][13] = struct.unpack('>i', file.read(4))
    packHeader[i]=list(chain(*packHeader[i])) #Deals with the tuple issue ((x,),(y,),...) -> (x,y,...)
    for j in range(dataLength):
        data[i][j] = struct.unpack('<h', file.read(2))
```

When it gets to this point it produces the error above. I'm not sure why. Both `dataLength` and `packets` are even numbers. So, imagined unpacking 2 bytes at a time shouldn't be an issue. Any thoughts?

**EDIT** I did check to see what would happen if I read in the data one byte at a time. So

```
data[i][j] = struct.unpack('<b', file.read(1))
```

and that worked fine. It just is not liking to unpack anything else.

**EDIT 2** I also just went ahead and made that slightly more compact by saying something like

```
data[i] = [struct.unpack('<h', file.read(2)) for j in range(dataLength)]
```

Still produces the same error - just more compactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, there was still iterations to be performed that when reading in 2 bytes (or more) at a time the data from the file was running out. The fix is to do something like the following

```
readBytes = value_wanting_to_be_read
dataLength = int(value2/readBytes)
```

and then in the actual loop

```
data[i] = [struct.unpack('<h', file.read(readBytes)) for j in range(dataLength)]
```

which works if `readBytes = 2`.